# How to use react-intl-tel-input in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I have started learning ReactJS from past 1 months and from last 1 week i stuck with a problem. I am using React with Firebase Phone Authentication. I want to use react-intl-tel-input for taking Phone input but when i install the package and write the code while writing i don't understand how to use the code in right way and getting this type of error `× TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'phoneNumber')`. or some times its give me this error `× TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'e')` I don't want that user have to type there country code manually with phone Number I want that user can simply select there country and type there phone number [image: Like this]

can Any one Please Help me i stuck in this from  more than 1 week tried different npm packages also try to use jQuery but nothing work for me.

this is my code ( App.js  )

```js
import React from 'react'
import firebase from './firebase'
import IntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input';
import 'react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  handleChange = (e) =>{
    const {name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
      })
  }
  
  configureCaptcha = () =>{
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {
        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
        this.onSignInSubmit();
        console.log("Recaptca varified")
      },
      defaultCountry: "IN"
    });
  }
  onSignInSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.configureCaptcha()
    const phoneNumber = "+91" + this.state.mobile
    console.log(phoneNumber)
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
          // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
          // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
          console.log("OTP has been sent")
          alert("OTP has been sent")
        }).catch((error) => {
          // Error; SMS not sent
          // ...
          console.log("SMS not sent")
          alert("SMS not sent")
        });
  }
  onSubmitOTP = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const code = this.state.otp
    console.log(code)
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then((result) => {
      // User signed in successfully.
      const user = result.user;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(user))
      alert("User is verified")
      // ...
    }).catch((error) => {
      // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
      // ...
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSignInSubmit}>
          <div id="sign-in-button"></div>

           <IntlTelInput
                containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
                inputClassName="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Number"
                value={this.state.phoneNumber}
                onPhoneNumberChange={this.handlePhoneChange} />
              
          {/* <input type="number" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile number" required onChange={this.handleChange}/> */}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <h2>Enter OTP</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitOTP}>
          <input type="number" name="otp" placeholder="OTP Number" required onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to share  your Firebase connection information publicly as it can be used by anyone. It is okay to post your Firebase code without adding your connection information and the community can still reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This library does not return a component, am pasting my component.

`phoneInput.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import intlTelInput from 'intl-tel-input';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css';


export const PhoneInput=({disabled,...rest})=>{
//rest may include-name, onChange, etc
    const [options,toggleOptions]=useState({
        allowDropdown:true,
        autoHideDialCode:false,
        initialCountry: "auto",
        separateDialCode:true,
        nationalMode:false,
        hadInitialPlaceholder:true,
        utilsScript: process.env.REACT_APP_PHONE_UTIL_SCRIPT,
        geoIpLookup: async function(callback) {
           await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_GEOIP_SERVICE)
           .then(res=>res.json())
           .then(({country})=>{
               callback(country)
           })},
        customPlaceholder: function(selectedCountryPlaceholder, selectedCountryData) {
            return "e.g. " + selectedCountryPlaceholder;
        },
    })
    useEffect(()=>{
        const input = document.querySelector("#signup-phone");
        if(!input) return;
        const iti=intlTelInput(input, {
            ...options
        });
        return()=>{
            iti.destroy();
        }
    },[])
    useEffect(()=>{
          toggleOptions(o=>({
              ...o,
              allowDropdown:!disabled
              //disable dropdown when disable flag is set
          }));
    },[disabled])
    return(
         <input
            disabled={disabled}
            type="tel"
            id="signup-phone"
            {...rest}
        />
    )
}
```

Utilised in
`signup.js`

```
<PhoneInput 
   name="phone_no"
   onChange={handleChange}
   disabled={loading}
   error={errors['phone_no']}
  />
```